# How to count accesses per hour from log file entries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, logging

I have a log-file where every line contains IP address, time of access, and the URL accessed. I want to count the accesses per hour.

Time of access data looks like this

```
[01/Jan/2017:14:15:45 +1000]
[01/Jan/2017:14:15:45 +1000]
[01/Jan/2017:15:16:05 +1000]
[01/Jan/2017:16:16:05 +1000]
```

How can I improve it so I don't need to set up the variable and if statement for every hour?

```
twoPM = 0
thrPM = 0
fouPM = 0
timeStamp = line.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]
formated_timeStamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timeStamp,'%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z').strftime('%H')
if formated_timeStamp == '14':
    twoPM +=1
if formated_timeStamp == '15':
    thrPM +=1
if formated_timeStamp == '16':
    fouPM +=1
```

Comment: Migrated from Code Review because it only barely "works", and essentially the question is asking for code to be rewritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can include the brackets into your `strptime` format description:

   ```
   datetime.datetime.strptime(line.strip(),'[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z]')
   ```
2. You can extract the hour using the `.hour` attribute of any `datetime.datetime` object:

   ```
   timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(…)
   hour = timestamp.hour
   ```
3. You can count the number of elements using a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

   ```
   from collections import Counter


   def read_logs(filename):
       with open(filename) as log_file:
            for line in log_file:
                timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(
                        line.strip(),
                        '[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z]')
                yield timestamp.hour


   def count_access(log_filename):
       return Counter(read_logs(log_filename))


   if __name__ == '__main__':
       print(count_access('/path/to/logs/'))
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You don't say whether the access-per-hour is daily, or what. So there's a lot of ways this could go. But here's a simple version:

```
import collections
import io

log_data = '''
[01/Jan/2017:14:15:45 +1000]
[01/Jan/2017:14:15:45 +1000]
[01/Jan/2017:15:16:05 +1000]
[01/Jan/2017:16:16:05 +1000]
'''

def filter_lines(file):
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('['):
            yield line

def extract_hour_from_line(seq):
    for line in seq:
        yield line.split(':')[1]

def access_per_hour(file):

    aph = collections.Counter(extract_hour_from_line(filter_lines(file)))
    return aph


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logfile = io.StringIO(log_data)
    aph = access_per_hour(logfile)
    print(aph)
```

This uses StringIO to convert the lines you provided as an example into an in-memory "file" that can be read. You can just open your log file, as you are no doubt already doing, to handle this normally.

The collections.Counter class takes a sequence and produces a dictionary-like object where the keys are the items from the sequence and the values are the counts - the number of times each one has appeared in the sequence.

This version of the code simply counts all of the distinct hour values, with no regard to what *date* the access occurs on. That is, 12:00 on Tuesday and 12:00 on Wednesday are considered the same hour. This is useful if you're just building a histogram of hour-by-hour demand.

If you want to do more advanced grouping, you might try using the `filter_lines` function to limit which lines you want to see, overall. For example, only lines between a range of dates, or only lines accessing a particular URL.

If you want to treat different days as distinct, you might use the `extract_hour_from_line` function to construct a distinct value - for example, concatenate the date and hour.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a dictionary:

```
per_hour = {}
per_hour[formated_timeStamp] += 1
```

so you'll get something as

```
{'0': 12, '1': 8, '2': 41, ...}
```

where the key represent an hour.