# Python calculate request rate per hour for each IP

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a dict in the following format
{str: [datetime_object]}

example:

```
test_data={'127.0.0.1':[datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 3, 48), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 3, 0, 53)],
    '127.0.0.2':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 30, 0, 15, 10), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 18, 29), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 18, 41), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 18, 49), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 32), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 40), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 46), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 22), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 23, 0, 0)],
    '127.0.0.3':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 19, 34), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 19, 39)],
    '127.0.0.4':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 20, 36), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 20, 41)],
    '127.0.0.5':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 5)],
    '127.0.0.6':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 6)],
    '127.0.0.7':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 5)],
    '127.0.0.8':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 34), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 38)],
    '127.0.0.9': [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 22, 3), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 23, 5)],
    '127.0.0.10':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 10, 22), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 12, 27)],
    '127.0.0.11':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 3, 11, 46), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 3, 13, 54)],
    '127.0.0.12':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 3, 13, 9), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 3, 13, 17)]}
```

These entries is the requests datetime received from each IP

I need to calculate the average request count per hour for each IP

my current try end at this code

```
def count_accesses():
    for key, value in ip_request_datetime_dict.items():
        for recived in value:
            yield recived.hour

for x in count_accesses():
    print(x)
```

the code above based on this solution
[How to count accesses per hour from log file entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814191/how-to-count-accesses-per-hour-from-log-file-entries)

A correct solution output could be a dictionary contains the rates. example:

- Th average request rate for this 127.0.0.1 is 2 request per hour, because there still 3 minutes to count full hour as you can see 02:03:48 -> 03:00:53
- Th average request rate for this 127.0.0.2 is 3 request per hour

  ip_hit_rate = {'127.0.0.1': 2,
  '127.0.0.2': 3,
  '127.0.0.3': 2,
  '127.0.0.4': 2,
  '127.0.0.5': 1,
  '127.0.0.6': 1}

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Are the lists guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: Why is `127.0.0.1` 2 request per hour? The entries in `test_data` for the ip was made on different dates?

Comment: i dont understant you average per hour....  what is the hour of reference?

Comment: @Chris thanks for pointing out, I have corrected the question

Comment: @Frenchy It's how many requests received from an IP in hour, we need to calculate the average  requests per hour for each IP

Comment: But I calculate the rate for 127.0.0.1 as a small fraction of 1 per hour, not 1 request every hour.

Comment: ok but for example a tick at 2h03, you begin your hour at 2h03 or 2h

Comment: @Frenchy tick at 2h03. so the result will be more accurate

Comment: ok i have found a solution with your lapse time corresponding

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools

res = {}
for k,v in test_data.items():  
    counts = [len(list(g)) for _, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(v), lambda x:(x.year, x.month, x.day, x.hour))]
    res[k] = round(sum(counts)/len(counts))
```

Output:

```
{'127.0.0.1': 1,
 '127.0.0.10': 2,
 '127.0.0.11': 2,
 '127.0.0.12': 2,
 '127.0.0.2': 3,
 '127.0.0.3': 2,
 '127.0.0.4': 2,
 '127.0.0.5': 1,
 '127.0.0.6': 1,
 '127.0.0.7': 1,
 '127.0.0.8': 2,
 '127.0.0.9': 2}
```

Comment: Thank you @Chris this looks more correct. If it can round results that would be great as this result will be put in a report. example 1.5 request per hour can be rounded to 2

Comment: @Salama Sure. You can use `round`. Please refer to the edit :)

Comment: good job, can you please modify the solution again so it can be more accurate, example 

'127.0.0.1':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 3, 48), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 3, 0, 53)],

the average request  count per hour is 2 because there still 3 minutes to count full hour as you can see 02:03:48 -> 03:00:53, but the current solution gives 1

Comment: @Salama the example you are giving differs from the sample (`'127.0.0.1':[datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 28, 2, 3, 48), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 3, 53)]`. You can update your post and let me know which one you want to use :)

Comment: I have Updated the question, it's more accurate to calculate distance between 2 hour and check if it's > 59 minute then we consider it as a new hour beginning

Comment: Would be more appreciated if you fix it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would calculate the requests per hour:

```
import datetime

test_data={'127.0.0.1':[datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 28, 2, 3, 48), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 3, 53)],
    '127.0.0.2':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 30, 0, 15, 10), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 18, 29), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 18, 41), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 18, 49), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 32), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 40), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 46), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 22), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 23, 0, 0)],
    '127.0.0.3':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 19, 34), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 19, 39)],
    '127.0.0.4':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 20, 36), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 20, 41)],
    '127.0.0.5':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 5)],
    '127.0.0.6':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 6)],
    '127.0.0.7':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 5)],
    '127.0.0.8':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 34), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 38)],
    '127.0.0.9': [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 22, 3), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 23, 5)],
    '127.0.0.10':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 10, 22), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 12, 27)],
    '127.0.0.11':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 3, 11, 46), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 3, 13, 54)],
    '127.0.0.12':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 3, 13, 9), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 3, 13, 17)]}

def delta_to_hours(delta):
    return delta.days * 24 + delta.seconds / 3600

def calc_rate(values):
    num = len(values)
    if num <= 1:
        return 1
    diff = delta_to_hours(values[-1] - values[0])
    return num / diff

rates = {key:calc_rate(value) for key,value in test_data.items()}
print(rates)
```

The Output is:

```
{
'127.0.0.1': 0.02777724195135125, 
'127.0.0.2': 0.1925248083665102, 
'127.0.0.3': 1440.0, 
'127.0.0.4': 1440.0, 
'127.0.0.5': 1, 
'127.0.0.6': 1, 
'127.0.0.7': 1, 
'127.0.0.8': 1800.0, 
'127.0.0.9': 116.12903225806451, 
'127.0.0.10': 57.599999999999994, 
'127.0.0.11': 56.25, 
'127.0.0.12': 900.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.groupby` is cool, but sometimes it looks like a dark magic hard to comprehend.
`collections.Counter` might also help you out, and it is easier to use:

```
import datetime
from collections import Counter

test_data={'127.0.0.1':[datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 28, 2, 3, 48), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 3, 53)],
    '127.0.0.2':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 30, 0, 15, 10), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 18, 29), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 18, 41), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 18, 49), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 32), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 40), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 46), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 22), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 23, 0, 0)],
    '127.0.0.3':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 19, 34), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 19, 39)],
    '127.0.0.4':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 20, 36), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 20, 41)],
    '127.0.0.5':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 5)],
    '127.0.0.6':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 6)],
    '127.0.0.7':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 5)],
    '127.0.0.8':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 34), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 21, 38)],
    '127.0.0.9': [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 22, 3), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 23, 5)],
    '127.0.0.10':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 10, 22), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 12, 27)],
    '127.0.0.11':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 3, 11, 46), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 3, 13, 54)],
    '127.0.0.12':  [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 3, 13, 9), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 3, 13, 17)]}

def extract_hour(d: datetime.datetime):
    return d.date(), d.hour

result = {}
for k, v in test_data.items():
    cnt = Counter(map(extract_hour, v))
    result[k] = sum(cnt.values()) / len(cnt)

print(result)
```

will output

```
{
    '127.0.0.1': 1.0, 
    '127.0.0.2': 3.0, 
    '127.0.0.3': 2.0, 
    '127.0.0.4': 2.0, 
    '127.0.0.5': 1.0, 
    '127.0.0.6': 1.0, 
    '127.0.0.7': 1.0, 
    '127.0.0.8': 2.0, 
    '127.0.0.9': 2.0, 
    '127.0.0.10': 2.0, 
    '127.0.0.11': 2.0, 
    '127.0.0.12': 2.0
}
```

Comment: good job, can you please modify the solution again so it can be more accurate, example '127.0.0.1': [datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 2, 3, 48), datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 3, 0, 53)], the average request count per hour is 2 because there still 3 minutes to count full hour as you can see 02:03:48 -> 03:00:53, but the current solution gives 1

Comment: But those are different days in `test_data`! May 28th and May 31st.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I have modified the question, but still not getting accurate output

Comment: I think you might want to define your goal more formally.
For example, what result would you expect for `[(2016, 5, 31, 2, 5), (2016, 5, 31, 2, 25), (2016, 5, 31, 2, 30), (2016, 5, 31, 2, 35), (2016, 5, 31, 3, 10), ]`?

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution with the timing of one hour:

```
result={}
for k in test_data.keys():
    ref = test_data[k][0]
    counter= []
    c = 1
    for h in range(1, len(test_data[k])):
        if (test_data[k][h] - ref).total_seconds() / 3600 < 1.0:
            c = c + 1
        else:
            counter.append(c)
            c = 1
            ref = test_data[k][h]
            if h == len(test_data[k])-1:
                counter.append(c)

    result[k] = float(c) if len(counter) == 0 else float(sum(counter)) / len(counter) 

print(result)
```

output:

```
{'127.0.0.1': 2.0, 
'127.0.0.2': 3.0, 
'127.0.0.3': 2.0, 
'127.0.0.4': 2.0, 
'127.0.0.5': 1.0, 
'127.0.0.6': 1.0, 
'127.0.0.7': 1.0, 
'127.0.0.8': 2.0, 
'127.0.0.9': 2.0, 
'127.0.0.10': 2.0, 
'127.0.0.11': 2.0, 
'127.0.0.12': 2.0}
```